# How to change the route when an element is hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I know that `ng-mouse=ng-href...` is not proper syntax, but it's what I am trying to do. How can I change the `href` when the mouse hovers over an element?

```html
<ul id="optionsList">
  <li ng-repeat="link in links">
    <a ng-mouse=ng-href="#/{{link.linkName}}" />
      <div class="hvr-bubble-right">{{link.linkName}}</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How is this related to CSS?

Comment: Is `ng-mouse` a directive you made? It looks like what you're wanting is to use `ng-mouseover`. Have it call a function in your controller that returns what you're wanting.

Comment: @actimel probably bcoz of `class ="hvr-bubble-right"` :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to do something like:

```
ng-mouseover="yourFunction(link.linkName)"
```

and then in controller:

```
$scope.yourFunction=function(where){
    $window.location.href = where;
    //or $state.go('some.state'); if you use states.
}
```

Remember to include  '$window' or '$state' in your controller depending on which you use.